# What is the best approach to distribute a project in both windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, jython

So there is this particular jython project that needs a couple of dependencies, such as Jenkins, some kind of subversion, and this needs to be done on windows.

Would it be sane of me to consider using pip to help install all of these items, or should I look elsewhere, such as NSIS?

Update:
I really should've rephrase this - my fault for asking the question late at night.
There's an automated testing project that has the following dependencies:

- Java JDK
- Jython
- Ant
- Robot Framework
- subversion
- Jenkins

I personally prefer to run on Linux, but people that need to use this are typically Windows users. I'm confident enough to write a script to install all of this on Linux, but what I *want* is to have a script / installer that would install the relevent tools.

I would prefer to have a single script to do all of this - it's easy on Ubuntu with apt-get; but on windows, this quickly becomes non-trivial.

What is the best way to try and do this? Should I create separate installers for separate OS

Comment: Can you elaborate how you plan to do that

Comment: Yes, how would you use pip to install them? I don't believe there are pip packages for them.

Comment: pip installs python source packages. Jenkins is java. Subversion is something else but not python. So, no, not sane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` is the acronym for `pip install packages, python packages`, and it only install Python packages.

Since Jenkins and Subversion are not Python packages, as far as I know, you can't install them, and it is not "sane".

Unfortunately there is no single established tool to install everything in every platform.

Use `pip` to install all your python packages, and prefer to use `virtualenv` to create isolated Python environments to manage your projects.

Answer (score 2):

Since pip only installs python packages and Jenkins isn't a python package (it's written in Java), you cannot use it to install those packages.

You should totally take a look to virtualenv, but if you need to do a "double click" installer for your project in Windows i think that NSIS is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully using [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) to create an executable installer for Windows, Linux and OSX. The application is Java and it bundles JRE. Install4j creates installer for each specified platform using respective JRE. So far it worked great on Windows and it somewhat works on Linux and OSX (e.g. in new version of install4j, JRE for Java 1.8 is not bundled properly for linu, so the JRE is preinstalled, but it could be automated). It also allows you to run non-interactive installer.